# Error compiling zabbix 3.4

Tags: visual-studio, zabbix

The pcre library is used. When compiling in win32, there is no error

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. By know you even haven't articulated an actual question!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The topic can be closed

Comment: Answer your own question with the steps you make to solve the problem. Then accept your own question.